# Correct way to extract Translation from Essential Matrix through SVD

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, svd

I calibrated my camera and found the intrinsic parameters(K). Also I have calculated the Fundamental Matrix (F).

Now E= K_T* F * K . So far so good.

Now we pass the Essential Matrix(E) to the SVD to use the decomposition values (U,W,V) to extract the Rotation and Translation:

```
 essentialMatrix = K.Transpose().Mul(fund).Mul(K);
 CvInvoke.cvSVD(essentialMatrix, wMatrix, uMatrix, vMatrix, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.SVD_TYPE.CV_SVD_DEFAULT);
```

** Question) At this point, two methods have been proposed, and it has confused me which one really give out the right answer- specifically for Translation:

At first method [enter link description here](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~cer/arv/readings/old_mkss.pdf) the author suggests to compute the R,T as following:

[image]

But in Second method [http://isit.u-clermont1.fr/~ab/Classes/DIKU-3DCV2/Handouts/Lecture16.pdf] the author provides another formula for T which is +U , -U as shown below:

[image]

I am implementing this on C# .Net using openCv libraries. Anybody knows which Translation Formula is the right one?

Comment: The link for the second method is dead. The document moved to: http://igt.ip.uca.fr/~ab/Classes/DIKU-3DCV2/Handouts/Lecture16.pdf

Answer (score 4):

the first solution shows the matrix representation of the cross product with vector t (so first solution = [t]x ), while the second solution shows just the translation vector t (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix).

The definition of [t]x is:

[image]

(from http://gandalf-library.sourceforge.net/tutorial/report/img148.png)

Comment: In First solution, T1,T2 are nonZero 3X3 matrices but in fact as a translation t , I need 3X1 matrix. how should I extract 3X1 from a nonZero 3X3 matrix without losing information?

Comment: if you extract translation with SVD, the translation vector is `SVD(E).u.col(2)`, as it is described in the second method of your post. how do you extract your 3x3 translation matrix? you can also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639106/camera-motion-from-corresponding-images for further information

Comment: I used the 1st method mentioned above to extract T1,T2 that either are 3X3.  Am I doing something wrong?
In the link provided, again the guy jumped from calculation of t1,t2 to t without mentioning the conversion/relation between t1,t2 and t as I restate it below:
t1 = decomp.u.col(2); //u3
t2 = -decomp.u.col(2); //u3
new_pos = old_pos + -R.t()*t;

Comment: since you're are using SVD, your translation vector (3x1) is the 3rd column of U (`decomp.u.col(2)` returns a 3x1 vector). by using SVD, you get 4 possible solutions, 2 for `R` and 2 for `t`. to get the correct solution of both, you can use triangulation. if you read the other question carefully, you'll see that between ` t1\t2 = decomp.u.col(2);` and `new_pos = old_pos + -R.t()*t;` the triangulation is done (link provided in other question). Also read the comments, which points out a mistake in SVD computation