# determine camera rotation and translation matrix from essential matrix

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I am trying to extract rotation matrix and translation matrix from essential matrix. 
I took these answers as reference:

[Correct way to extract Translation from Essential Matrix through SVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940663/correct-way-to-extract-translation-from-essential-matrix-through-svd)

[Extract Translation and Rotation from Fundamental Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150152/extract-translation-and-rotation-from-fundamental-matrix)

Now I've done the above steps applying SVD to essential matrix, but here comes the problem. According to my understanding about this subject, both R and T has two answers, which leads to 4 possible solutions of [R|T]. However only one of the solutions would fit in the physical situation.

My question is how can I determine which one of the 4 solutions is the correct one?

I am just a beginner on studying camera position. So if possible, please make the answer be as clear (but simple) as possible. Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is testing a point 3D position using the possible solution, that is, a reconstructed point  will be in front of both cameras in only one of the possible 4 solutions.
So assuming one camera matrix is P = [I|0], you have 4 options for the other camera, but only one of the pairs will place such point in front them.

More details in Hartley and Zisserman's *multiple view geometry* (page 259)

If you can use Opencv (version 3.0+), you count with a function called "recoverPose", this function will do that job for you.

Ref: OpenCV documentation, http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html